# Pre-90s movie about brother and sister with telekinesis abilities; sister makes a bird explode with her mind

Tags: story-identification, movie, mind-control, telekinesis

A movie that I have seen as a child back in early 90s. The movie starts with a blond lady having a breakfast in the garden, and then she gets annoyed with this bird on the tree, so she would make that bird explode with her mind.

Next seen is her brother returning home, and him remembering why he had to go away, because he accidentally killed his friend at the party, trying to show his telekinesis abilities to everyone, his friend ends up thrown out of the balcony.

So this lady becomes very violent, and try’s to control everyone through a tv. And the siblings will fight each other at the end of the movie. I don’t remember how it ends.

It’s 70s or 80s movie. The blonde lady looked like Sharon Stone. But I don’t think it was her, I went over her filmography a few times.

Comment: Hi there! That's some good info already, but could you maybe take a look at [thse guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parts of this sound like [*Scanners III: The Takeover*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanners_III:_The_Takeover). It

- was made in 1992
- starts with the brother accidentally pushing a friend off a balcony and putting himself into exile
- features a telepathic woman whose medication makes her psychopathic
- said (brunette) woman, enjoying breakfast on a balcony, makes a pigeon explode in the following clip **(warning, pigeon explosion)**:

Comment: Good catch! I found a clip showing the bird exploding, so I thought I'd edit it into your answer :)

Comment: @Jenayah yikes! Thank you. This must be it.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much James, this is the movie I have been searching for. I don’t know why I remembered her as blonde though 